# Custom Draw view not showing

Tags: java, android

I created a custom view to draw some shapes on it but my problem is that nothing is showed on the view. I get no error messages or crash. My custom class looks the like:

```
public class DrawableView extends View {
  private Paint mPaint;
  private MyDrawable mDrawableObj; // object to draw
  private RectF mRectBounds;

public DrawableView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public DrawableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public DrawableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr){
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int h = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
}

public void setDrawableObj(MyDrawable obj, boolean forcePrepare) {
    final boolean needPrepare = forcePrepare || (mDrawableObj != null) ;
    mDrawableObj = obj;
    mDrawableObj.setView(this);
    if (needPrepare) {
        prepareObject();
        invalidate();
    }
}

private void init() {
    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    final int padLeft = getPaddingLeft();
    final int padTop = getPaddingTop();
    final float xpad = (float) (padLeft + getPaddingRight());
    final float ypad = (float) (padTop + getPaddingBottom());

    final float ww = (float) w - xpad - 1;
    final float hh = (float) h - ypad - 1;

    mRectBounds = new RectF(0, 0, ww, hh);
    mRectBounds.offsetTo(padLeft, padTop);

    prepareObject();
}

public void prepareObject() {
    if (mDrawableObj != null)
        mDrawableObj.prepare(mRectBounds);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (mDrawableObj != null)
        mDrawableObj.draw(canvas, mRectBounds);
    else {
        canvas.drawRect(mRectBounds, mPaint);
    }
}
```

My layout file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.hello.myApp.Draw">

<DrawableView.DrawableView
    android:id="@+id/drawtest_drawableView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/leftMenu"
    android:padding="4dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Do you have any idea why I have just a white screen?

Comment: The third constructor has no `init()`

Comment: You're right @MiguelIsla. I added init() to the third constructor but I get the same result.

Comment: What's MyDrawable?

Comment: It is an interface which contains the setView, draw and prepare methods.

Comment: have checked Height and Width. in your case value of height and Width may have zero. That's why your View is not visible.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I debugged it and for the height I get 0. I changed it to be equal with the width (so the dimension is width x width) but still nothing shows.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    public void init() {
         if (isInEditMode())
                return;
         //code
         //...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I copy/pasted your code into my IDE and ran it (though I had to create a fake `MyDrawable` interface to satisfy the compiler). I'm just putting an instance of `DrawableView` into a `LinearLayout` and I see it drawing just fine.

My layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.stackoverflow.DrawableView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I see:

[image]

It makes sense that I see only the blue rectangle, because this is your `onDraw()` implementation:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (mDrawableObj != null)
        mDrawableObj.draw(canvas, mRectBounds);
    else {
        canvas.drawRect(mRectBounds, mPaint);
    }
}
```

Given that `setDrawableObj(MyDrawable obj, boolean forcePrepare)` is never called in the code you posted, the `else` is always what's being executed/drawn.

Comment: I've tried this and I get the same result. In my code I call the 
    setDrawableObj(MyDrawable obj, boolean forcePrepare) method and it works fine but after that in the onDraw the mDrawableObj has a null value. This is why it draws only a rectangle. Do you have any idea what can cause this?